# win32com Excel PasteSpecial

Tags: python, excel, win32com, vba

I'm having some trouble with PasteSpecial in python.  Here's the sample code:

```
import win32com.client as win32com
from win32com.client import constants

xl = win32com.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add ()
Sheet1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

# Fill in some summy formulas
for i in range(10):
    Sheet1.Cells(i+1,1).Value = "=10*"+str(i+1)

Sheet1.Range("A1:A16").Copy()
Sheet1.Range("C1").Select()
Sheet1.PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Paste() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Paste'
```

I know that paste is a keyword argument because of the MSDN here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx

Any idea why it won't let me do this? Can't really find much on the web.

Edit for solution(s):

```
import win32com.client as win32com
from win32com.client import constants

xl = win32com.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add ()
Sheet1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

# Fill in some summy formulas
for i in range(10):
    Sheet1.Cells(i+1,1).Value = "=10*"+str(i+1)

Sheet1.Range("A1:A16").Copy()
Sheet1.Range("C1").PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues)
# OR this I just found right after I posted this works as well:
xl.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: I don't work with python but try this `Sheet1.Range("C1").PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues)`

Comment: Regarding your edit: You should avoid the use of `.Select/Selection`. You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) Excel-VBA link

Comment: Based upon other lines of code that you were not having a problem with, this should eliminate the copy & paste special altogether. `Sheet1.Range("C1:C16") = Sheet1.Range("A1:A16").Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't work with python but to do a `PasteSpecial` in Excel-VBA, you have to mention the cell where you want to perform the pastespecial, so try like

```
Sheet1.Range("C1").PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues)
```

If you want a simple paste then I guess this should work

```
Sheet1.Paste
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get value for xlPasteFormats by execute macro in Excel vb:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

The value for xlPasteFormats is `-4122` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype) for all codes).

In Python script you can use

```
xlSheet.Range("A7:H7").Copy()
xlSheet.Range("A%s:H%s"%(r,r)).PasteSpecial(Paste=-4122)
```

Comment: I also had issues retrieving the constant from `win32com.client.constant` so I had to put the constant hardcoded in my mode (e.g. `xlPasteComments = -4144`).